# How to create wss request on localhost on local machine

Tags: websocket

We are using two HPPS servers, one using lampp, another using NodeJS. The lampp HTTPS is using 443 as default port.

## https://localhost:443/test/Index.html

```
var websocketEndpoint = 'wss://localhost:9000';
 connection = new WebSocket(websocketEndpoint);
 connection.onmessage = function (ping) {
    name = message.data;
 }
```

We have created seperate HTTPS server under /temp/ folder using NodeJS as below.

## Index.js

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var expressWss = require('express-ws')(express());
var appWs = expressWss.app;
appWs.use('/uploads',express.static('./uploads'));

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('fake-keys/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('fake-keys/crt.pem')
};

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 9000);
https.createServer(options, appWs).listen(port, function () {
   console.log('Listening on port:' + port);
});
```

When we are making request via ws:// without HTTPS. It is working fine but if we are making request via wss:// it is generating below error on locahost.

"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:9000."

Though, we tried to resolve the issue by directly hitting the NodeJS url via firefox browser and accepting SSL certificate(self signed) but issue still appearing.

Please suggest if there is any other way to resolve the error.